# Manual ACK for AggregatingMessageHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm trying to build integration scenario like this `Rabbit -> AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL) -> DirectChannel -> AggregatingMessageHandler -> DirectChannel -> AmqpOutboundEndpoint`.

I want to aggregate messages in-memory and release it if I aggregate 10 messages, or if timeout of 10 seconds is reached. I suppose this config is OK:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "amqpInputChannel")
public MessageHandler aggregator(){
    AggregatingMessageHandler aggregatingMessageHandler = new AggregatingMessageHandler(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor(), new SimpleMessageStore(10));
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setCorrelationStrategy(new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy(AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID));
    //default false
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);  //when grp released (using strategy), remove group so new messages in same grp create new group
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);   //when expired because timeout and not because of strategy, still send messages grouped so far
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)));  //timeout after X

    //timeout is checked only when new message arrives!!
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setReleaseStrategy(new TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)));
    aggregatingMessageHandler.setOutputChannel(amqpOutputChannel());
    return aggregatingMessageHandler;
}
```

Now, my question is - is there any easier way to manualy ack messages except creating my own implementation of AggregatingMessageHandler in this way:

```
public class ManualAckAggregatingMessageHandler extends AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler {
        ...

    private void ackMessage(Channel channel, Long deliveryTag){
        try {
            Assert.notNull(channel, "Channel must be provided");
            Assert.notNull(deliveryTag, "Delivery tag must be provided");
            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MessagingException("Cannot ACK message", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterRelease(MessageGroup messageGroup, Collection<Message<?>> completedMessages) {
        Object groupId = messageGroup.getGroupId();
        MessageGroupStore messageStore = getMessageStore();
        messageStore.completeGroup(groupId);

        messageGroup.getMessages().forEach(m -> {
            Channel channel = (Channel)m.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL);
            Long deliveryTag = (Long)m.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG);
            ackMessage(channel, deliveryTag);
        });

        if (this.expireGroupsUponCompletion) {
            remove(messageGroup);
        }
        else {
            if (messageStore instanceof SimpleMessageStore) {
                ((SimpleMessageStore) messageStore).clearMessageGroup(groupId);
            }
            else {
                messageStore.removeMessagesFromGroup(groupId, messageGroup.getMessages());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to do it after your help. Most important parts: Connection factory must have `factory.setPublisherConfirms(true)`. `AmqpOutboundEndpoint` must have this two settings: `outboundEndpoint.setConfirmAckChannel(manualAckChannel())` and `outboundEndpoint.setConfirmCorrelationExpressionString("#root")`, and this is implementation of rest of classes:

```
public class ManualAckPair {
    private Channel channel;
    private Long deliveryTag;

    public ManualAckPair(Channel channel, Long deliveryTag) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.deliveryTag = deliveryTag;
    }

    public void basicAck(){
        try {
            this.channel.basicAck(this.deliveryTag, false);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractManualAckAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor extends AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor {
    public static final String MANUAL_ACK_PAIRS = PREFIX + "manualAckPairs";

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> aggregateHeaders(MessageGroup group) {
        Map<String, Object> aggregatedHeaders = super.aggregateHeaders(group);
        List<ManualAckPair> manualAckPairs = new ArrayList<>();
        group.getMessages().forEach(m -> {
            Channel channel = (Channel)m.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL);
            Long deliveryTag = (Long)m.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG);
            manualAckPairs.add(new ManualAckPair(channel, deliveryTag));
        });
        aggregatedHeaders.put(MANUAL_ACK_PAIRS, manualAckPairs);
        return aggregatedHeaders;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class ManualAckServiceActivator {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "manualAckChannel")
public void handle(@Header(MANUAL_ACK_PAIRS) List<ManualAckPair> manualAckPairs) {
    manualAckPairs.forEach(manualAckPair -> {
        manualAckPair.basicAck();
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you don't need such a complex logic for the aggregator.

You simply can acknowledge them after the aggregator release - in the service activator in between aggregator and that `AmqpOutboundEndpoint`.

And right you have to use there `basicAck()` with the `multiple` flag to `true`:

```
@param multiple true to acknowledge all messages up to and
```

Well, for that purpose you definitely need a custom `MessageGroupProcessor` to extract the highest `AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG` for the whole batch and set it as a header for the output aggregated message.

You might just extend `DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor` and override its `aggregateHeaders()`:

```
/**
 * This default implementation simply returns all headers that have no conflicts among the group. An absent header
 * on one or more Messages within the group is not considered a conflict. Subclasses may override this method with
 * more advanced conflict-resolution strategies if necessary.
 *
 * @param group The message group.
 * @return The aggregated headers.
 */
protected Map<String, Object> aggregateHeaders(MessageGroup group) {
```

Comment: If I ACK messages after aggregator release, isn't there possibility that messages does not reach `AmqpOutboundEndpoint` but I still ACK them (meaning they are lost from AMQP queue)? I know this is highly unlikely but still a problem?

Comment: ??? You are acking receving messages. That's not related to the produced. Or do you want to ack only in case you send to the some further AMQP queue properly?

Comment: Yes, I want to ACK receiving messages (in `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL)`). Basically wait 10 seconds in order to aggregate messages and release them to new exchange. If release (to AMQP exchange) is successful, only then ACK received messages (on received AMQP queue). I need some kind of message throttler/aggregator here.

Comment: OK. So, use those `AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL` and the highest `AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG` headers as options for the `basicAck()` in the `AmqpOutboundEndpoint`'s `confirmCalback`. See its `confirmAckChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-outbound-channel-adapter

Comment: is highest the correct here? Since i can aggregate say out of 1 2 3 4 messages only (2,3,4) and send them, while 1 still waits to be aggregated and sent. I suppose that if I use highest, I loose 1?

Comment: OK. So you can build a custom header like `deliveryTags` for all the numbers of the messages to aggregate and use `basicAck()` in the loop to ack them all separately.

Comment: The same `aggregateHeaders()` might helpful here

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Could you just tell me how to use `setConfirmAckChannel`? Should it be set to `amqpInputChannel` in my case? Where to create this loop for acking - in the `setConfirmCorrelationExpression`?

Comment: `setConfirmCorrelationExpressionString` must be `#root` to refer to the whole `requestMessage`, so you will be able to get those desired headers there. `setConfirmAckChannel` must be some new channel with the `ServiceActivator` subscribed to that channel with the logic to loop over `deliverTags` header in its input message.

Comment: You can take a look about `confirms` in this sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/amqp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159046/discussion-between-bojanv55-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Please, raise a new SO question - to much discussion to confuse others